# Shorter way to express regular expression matching a space or "&nbsp;"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression that is getting some information from a string. I need the values on both sides of either a space or a nbsp. Problem is that I believe the only way I can specify either or is with groups and bar. Is there a more concise or readable way to do this? There has to be!

Using Regex in C#

Regex:

```
(\d)(?:(?:\s)|(?:&nbsp;))(\d)
```

Matching:

```
5 6
5&nbsp;6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those nested parentheses and `?:` are unnecessary. This should be sufficient:

```
(\d)(?:\s|&nbsp;)(\d)
```